# GData with Oauth with Service Account

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gdata

I am in a strange problem. I am writing an application in core java which needs to access its own account at google docs. So after doing a lot of googling, I found that OAuth2.0 with Service Account is something I am looking for. But I am not using App Engine or anything. Its a simple application. I don't know how can I use the OAuth. I have written below code and I dont know how to proceed further. Looking for someone to guide me further:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                                                                    .setServiceAccountId(EMAIL)
                                                                    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPE)
                                                                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("lib/key.p12")).build();

SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("My test Service");
             //service .setOAuthCredentials(parameters, signer);
```

Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google Documents List API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) page, it seems that the Google Docs API is now deprecated, and you should instead use the Google Drive API. It also uses OAuth2, and thus also supports service accounts. For a quick start tutorial on connecting to Google Drive and creating a new file, see [Quickstart: Run a Drive App in Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java). For more Java specific OAuth2 information, see the [google-api-java-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2) page, and in particular the [Service Accounts](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts) section of that page.